# Unreal Engine 4 Blueprint integration with Google Play Leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am becoming crazy, and have been stuck for a while on this. Is there any tutorial in BP integration with android? I have tried to follow flappy bird as much as possible. But there is something is not working for me.

Here is a bit of what I am doing to know if anything see something wrong.

1. My Game is in published state in Game Services.
   [image]
2. I have configured this on my project properties
   [image]
3. On my game instance when i initialize my game I create my local Data and read the leaderboard, after that I sync this leaderboard with my local data.
   [image]
4. On my main menu I try to show the leaderboard on the click of one of the buttons
   [image]

when I run the game nothing is being displayed. What am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so everything was right, my issue was that the android package name was slightly diferent (1 capital) in UE4.8 and play developer console. Check your Strings :P.